# Spring Security login failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Use customized datasource and Spring Security password encoder, but login failed.
Spring Boot version 2.7.0
I first register a user named "132456", passsword "123456", then login, but failed;
Then I create a test class: print true

```java
    @Test
    public void selectTest() {
        UserDetails userDetails = userInfoService.loadUserByUsername("123456");
        System.out.println(userDetails);
        boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches("123456", userDetails.getPassword());
        System.out.println(matches);
    }
```

**Spring Security config**

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    UserInfoService userInfoService;

    @Autowired
    Gson gson;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        .... login url has pass
        http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/login").permitAll()
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                    this.sendMessage(response, authentication);
                })
                .failureHandler((request, response, exception) ->
                        jwtTokenFilter.sendError(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "username or password error"));
        http.logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(false);
        http.rememberMe().disable();
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userInfoService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authProvider;
    }

}
```

**userServiceImpl**

```java
// use mybatisplus framework
@Service
public class UserInfoServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<UserInfoMapper, UserInfo> implements UserInfoService {

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LambdaQueryWrapper<UserInfo> queryWrapper = new LambdaQueryWrapper<>();
        queryWrapper.eq(UserInfo::getUsername, username);
        return getOne(queryWrapper);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean create(UserInfoDTO userInfoDTO) {
        userInfoDTO.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userInfoDTO.getPassword()));
        return save(BeanUtil.copyProperties(userInfoDTO, UserInfo.class));
    }
}
```

login success, then return token.

Answer (score 1):

Omg, I forgot to override the interface `UserDetails` inner method: `isEnabled()`, Hahahah. Spent two hours finding this bug.

```java
/**
 * Indicates whether the user is enabled or disabled. A disabled user cannot be
 * authenticated.
 * @return <code>true</code> if the user is enabled, <code>false</code> otherwise
 */
boolean isEnabled();
```